# How to make hyperlinks in iOS Mail app?

Tags: ios, mail.app, links

Update:
Apple has now added this feature to the iOS Mail app. See accepted answer for details.

Original post:
Using the standard iOS Mail app, how do you make a hyperlink from part of the text you are composing?

In the animated gif below, I want to have the word "Lincoln" contain the hyperlink instead of pasting it below (which looks ugly), but as you can see there are no options to do so in the popup menus.

[image]

Making links like this is easy here on [StackExchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), within Gmail, Word, Excel, google Docs, etc... but for some reason, I've missed how to do it in the iOS Mail app.

How can I get this level of polished mail with hyperlinks on iOS?

Comment: @NimeshNeema I don't believe this is a duplicate, but if you believe it is, can you please provide a clear answer to the question with reasoning? I looked carefully through all the posts on that page, testing some based upon it, and still do not see how to do it. Furthermore, as pointed out by some on that page, there is a confusion over whether iOS is being referred to since some answers involve keyboard shortcuts which don't apply to iOS

Comment: @NimeshNeema I don’t see this as an exact duplicate at all - see my answer why. I’ve removed the “meta” portion of the question as well. Great question Tony!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iOS Mail app **now** has this feature, as demonstrated in the following screen recording:

[image]

The animated gif also shows how one can edit the link.

Not sure when this feature was added, but it provides exactly what was asked for in the original question. For the screen recording I used iOS 17.0.3 on an iPhone XR.

Answer (score 3):

I always compose my mails then save them as draft which lets the processing of links happen. Have you verified you’ve given the software time to process what you type?

This is the simple way described here: [Create hyperlink on Mail.app/Notes.app on iOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/347405/create-hyperlink-on-mail-app-notes-app-on-ios)

Your adding an alternate text needs something more complex and since Mail does not support markdown or other editing like that, you need to compose in another program and then copy/paste/mail if you don’t want to have the full link typed out and then converted.

The Drafts app is my editor of choice for this. The first line of the document becomes the subject when you use the Markdown Mail quick action (tap the icon on the top far right)

[image: Drafts app example of a markdown email]

This gives you exactly the alternate text and full editing without mail.app needing a more sophisticated editing suite.

> How to markdown an email from Drafts app on iOS

[Markdown is awesome](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/368444/5472)

Comment: I appreciate @bmike stating clearly that "Mail does not support..." what I'm asking it to do in this question and furthermore providing a work-around using other apps. The process of making text into a hyperlink already involves switching between 2 apps (the Mail app plus the app you copy the link from) so introducing yet a 3rd app seems clumsy. So, I'll wait a couple of days to see if no one else has a solution before concluding it just can't be done in the Mail app alone. Thanks.

Comment: Yes - you cannot do this in mail on iOS 12 or below @TonyM **Mail does not support markdown or any other control** - should I change that in my answer to the top?

Comment: I completely accept that using a 3rd app, as you describe, works. In fact, to include links like I want, I've composed in google docs (which I mentioned) and then copy/pasted into an email. But, of course, that's not my question. So, as I said, I'll wait a few days in hopes that someone can solve it. I may even post a bounty. I'm used to my questions not being able to be answered, and I don't mind that.  But I always figure there are people out there who know more than I do. Thanks again.

Comment: Wonderful @TonyM let’s see if we all can learn. Check back in a month - no worries